# How to determine word length in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
let word : String = "hello"

var wordLength : Int = word.length //what to do here ?

for i in wordLength {
    let index = word.startIndex.advancedBy(i)
    print(word[index])
}
```

I want to print all the characters of the variable word individually, but i don't know how to determine when the word is over, or how often i have to loop until the whole word was printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let word = "hello"

for i in word.characters {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3: String + Emoji

```
let word = "Hello :-)  "

let wordLengthInt_0 = word.characters.count
// 12 (!!!!!)

let wordLengthInt_1 = word.utf16.count
// 13

let wordLengthInt_2 = (word as NSString).length
// 13
```